# MATLAB fmincon constraining vector elements

Tags: matlab, vector, constraints, element, minimization

Thanks for reading this, I have a matlab function 'myfun' that returns a scalar for a given input vector X. Now I am trying to minimize this function using fmincon but I have troubles constraining my output vector elements.

```
X0=1:1:10;

fhandle = @myfun;

lb=X0(1)*ones(length(X0),1);
ub=X0(end)*ones(length(X0),1);

[X]=fmincon(fhandle,X0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub);
```

First off, the elements cannot be smaller than X0(1) or larger than X0(end).
So far so good I think, but I have two more constraints for my output vector which I cannot find a solution for searching the questions here. The first one being

```
X(1)=X0(1) 
and 
X(end)=X0(end)
```

So the first and last elements must be set as constants.

My final constraint has to do with the change in value from element i to i+1, it has to be limited to a certain value A and element i must always be less than or equall to element i+1

```
X(i)<=X(i+1)
X(i+1)-X(i)<=E
```

An example output X with the following inputs X0 and A would be

```
X0=1:1:10;
E=3;

X=[1 1.1 1.2 1.4 1.7 2.0 2.7 4.7 7 10]
```

If somebody has tips on which parts/functions of fmincon or other minimization functions in Matlab to use, much appreciated!

PS: As I read the full post again I realize that my 2 constraints I'm looking for will imply the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question consists out of two parts:

1. Applying equality constraints on the design variables:

   Set the lower bound and upper bound to the same value:

   ```
   ub(1) = lb(1)
   lb(end) = ub(end);
   ```
2. Applying inequality constraints (`X(i+1)-X(i)<=E`):

   Reformulate your equations in the following matrix form:

   ```
   A*X <= B
   ```

   with

   ```
   A = zeros(9, 10);
   A(:, 1:9) = -eye(9)
   A(:, 2:10) = A(:, 2:10) + eye(9)

   B = ones(9, 1)*E;
   ```

Then you can call `fmincon` as follows:

```
[X]=fmincon(fhandle,X0,A,B,[],[],lb,ub);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you comment, I haven't got through on testing the inequality constraint as it keeps trying to adjust the values of x0(1) and x0(end) while optimizing, I have updated my code

Comment: Okay, for some reason Matlab tries to adjust the boundaries on the first iteration but does hold the constraints after the first.. Thank you for your time, everything seems to work out!